# Trouble Updating TextView Quantity via Button

Tags: java, android

Android Noob here. I am attempting to increment and decrement an TextView via plus and minus buttons. I am running into trouble connecting the method to the image view. Using Java 9. Assuming I'm making a basic mistake.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_tds_var"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_touchdowns_header" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_td_plus"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/home_tds_var"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_touchdowns_header"
    android:onClick="homeTDButtonPlus"/>
```

---

```
    package com.example.android.scorekeeper;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    int homeTouchdowns = 0;

    public void homeTDButtonPlus(View view) {
        homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns + 1;
        TextView home_tds_var = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_touchdowns_var);
        home_tds_var.setText(homeTouchdowns);
        //Updating the View
        //tvId.setText(String.valueOf(homeTouchdowns));
    }

}
```

Comment: ImageView or TextView

Comment: @GursheeshSingh textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your xml code, your `findViewById()` has an incorrect id:

```
TextView home_tds_var = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_touchdowns_var);
```

Should be:

```
TextView home_tds_var = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_tds_var);
```

I must say, using `onClick` in xml layout is discourage. You should create listeners in java code to decouple view from other application layers. A simple example:

```
TextView home_tds_var;
int homeTouchdowns = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    home_tds_var = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_tds_var);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_td_plus);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // Perform action on click   
                homeTouchdowns = homeTouchdowns + 1;
                home_tds_var.setText(homeTouchdowns);
            }
          });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
TextView home_tds_var = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_touchdowns_var);
```

to

```
TextView home_tds_var = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_tds_var);
```

Comment: Appears to be the same thing. Typo on your side?

Comment: your TextView id in XML doesn't match with the one in your java code

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void incrementHomeTdsVar(View view) {
    final TextView homeTdsView = findViewById(R.id.home_tds_var);

    int newValue = Integer.parseInt(homeTdsView.getText().toString()) + 1;

    homeTdsView.setText(String.valueOf(newValue));


    /* Home Score + 7 Increment */
    final TextView homeScoreView = findViewById(R.id.home_score_var);

    int homeScorePlus = Integer.parseInt(homeScoreView.getText().toString()) + 7;

    homeScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(homeScorePlus));
```